# how to use NSZombieEnabled

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I use xcode 3.4 , is there a steps to enable and use NSZombieEnabled

and will it be accepted by appstore

best regards

Comment: How to activate (duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/nszombieenabled-in-latest-xcode

Comment: About recommendability of the feature : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622079/break-on-exc-bad-access-in-xcode/1622091#1622091

Comment: your question reads 4.3. I wasn't sure there was a 4.3

Answer (score 1):

NSZombieEnabled is considered a "debug time" tool and has nothing as such to do with the App Store. You should not leave it enabled for an app you intend to distribute as no memory is ever released and the application will just continue to use and leak memory.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622079/break-on-exc-bad-access-in-xcode/1622091#1622091) for more info.

To enable in XCode 3.x have a look [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled)