# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access

I JUST started a new XCode Project. The code I have added in so far is this:

.h

```
@interface GameScreen : UIViewController {


    IBOutlet UIImageView *pimple;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *pimple;
-(void)checkcollision;
```

.m

```
@synthesize pimple;


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *myTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    pimple.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

    [self checkcollision];
}

- (void)checkcollision {

    if (label.text = @"0") {
        label.text += 1;
    }
}
```

My debugging console only sais one line:

Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
kill

Pls help

Comment: the void should be -(void) i dont know why that happened when i copied the code in

Comment: In the if statement, you probably mean to use ==, not =

Comment: Voted to close. Have we become DebugMyCode.stackexchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`label.text += 1;` is wrong. You can't add an integer onto an `NSString` object.

you will have to do `label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([label.text intValue] + 1)];`

Comment: Of course I assumed you wanted to add, appending it is also possible.

Comment: And check string equality like this `[label.text isEqualToString:@"0"]`

Answer (score 1):

you can use "NSZombieEnabled" to track your problem, [how to use it?](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), and also refer this link [Break on EXC_BAD_ACCESS in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622079/break-on-exc-bad-access-in-xcode/1622091#1622091)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you're assigning an integer to a NSString property.

```
label.text += 1;
```