# message sent to deallocated instance 0x1edf5720

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I am getting following message in log when app crashes

```
*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1edf5720
[Switching to process 9223 thread 0x2407]
[Switching to process 9223 thread 0x2407]
[unknown][unknown][unknown][unknown][unknown][unknown][unknown][unknown][unknown][unknown](gdb)
```

My question is pretty simple, I just want to know which one is **deallocated instance 0x1edf5720**.
I just want to know if there is any tool or some method by which i can know **0x1edf5720** is referring to which object Or where is the Zombie created exactly. Please note that i cann't use simulator to test. I must test it on device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your code and say what your trying to do? when the app crashes? so that people can help.

Comment: Use NSZombieEnabled flag to debug

Comment: Please post your code where it crashed and also paste code where you `alloc` `NSString`

Comment: how can i use NSZombieEnabled flag and how it works can you explain ?

Comment: @ankitmehta please refer this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622079/break-on-exc-bad-access-in-xcode/1622091#1622091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here one reason from bellow two options for crashed app.

**1.** You not allocated the variable of `NSString` and you `release` it.

**OR**

**2.** You already allocated but with `autorelease` propery like bellow..

```
   [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]; //Remove autorelease from here if you allocated with this keyword
```

Use `NSZombieEnabled` See the tutorial about that From this link [NSZombieEnabled-iPhone](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/16114-NSZombieEnabled-iPhone.html)

Comment: @ankitmehta  i also add link about `NSZombieEnabled` in my answer above and also see the option above i posted.. :)

Comment: I added the NSZombieEnabled argument but how can  i use to find out the object thats causing ?

Comment: checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4 and refer it dear :) hope its very helpful to you...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are releasing the `NSString` without allocating it.

You have to release only if you are allocating the values.

For eg:

```
NSString * tempString=[[NSString alloc]init];
```

now `[tempString release];` is valid.

if `NSString * tempString=[NSString string];` or   `NSString * tempString=@"";`

now `[tempString release];` is not valid.

Comment: Another way of saying that is that it's being over-released. Either he issued a `release` to some `autoreleased` variable (like you said) or issued an extra `release` somehow.