# EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception in the following code

Tags: ios, memory-management, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

```
    NSMutableArray *quesArrayForPar0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:

[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"We have a clearly stated vision for the next 5 years.", "-1", nil], 

[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Our organization has clearly established strategy to achieve the vision.", "-1", nil],

 [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"This strategy is implemented uniformly and effectively throughout our organization.", "-1", nil], 

[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"We are progressing as per our plan to realize this vision within the envisage time horizon.", "-1", nil]

, nil];
```

I really don't understand why the above code is throwing exception..!

Comment: Is `, "-1",` really in your code?

Comment: Ohh.. forgot to put @ before "-1".. A very silly mistake..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Break on EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS in XCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622079/break-on-exc-bad-access-in-xcode)

Comment: Read [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) Raywenderlich article carefully, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the inner mutable array you have assign two different objects. One is Obj-C string `@""` and other C string `""`.

So i have changed your code and its working.

```
NSMutableArray *quesArrayForPar0 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                    [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"We have a clearly stated vision for the next 5 years.", @"-1", nil],
                                    [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Our organization has clearly established strategy to achieve the vision.", @"-1", nil],
                                    [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"This strategy is implemented uniformly and effectively throughout our organization.", @"-1", nil],
                                    [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"We are progressing as per our plan to realize this vision within the envisage time horizon.", @"-1", nil]
                                    , nil];
```

Comment: One is an Obj-C string and the other is a C string