# How to find EXC_BAD_ACCESS variable from memory address in XCode6? [screenshot included]

Tags: ios, macos, variables, xcode6, exc-bad-access

This EXC_BAD_ACCESS error pops up once every 5~8 runs.

I am aware that it's caused by duplicate or bad variable usages, etc.

But I can't find exactly **WHERE** it is causing this error from my codes.

Is there a way to find out which variable is causing such problem?

[image]

Comment: Try exception break point to find where you getting the exact problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode     Use this link may help you...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Break on EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS in XCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622079/break-on-exc-bad-access-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zombie to get symbolicated info related to crash

Enable Zombie Objects by-

[image: /Users/sanjay/Desktop/Sc1.tiff]

And then, checking the Enable Zombie Objects checkbox,

[image: /Users/sanjay/Desktop/sc2.tiff]

Run(profile) your project in simulator -

The instruments will be launched as-

[image: /Users/sanjay/Desktop/sc3.tiff]

Instruments would show a message similar to the following:

[image: /Users/sanjay/Desktop/sc4.tiff]

Your next step should be to set an exception breakpoint in Xcode. When your app crashes, Xcode will pause your app at the point where the crash occurs. To set an exception breakpoint, open the breakpoint navigator by choosing View > Navigators > Show Breakpoint Navigator. Click the + button at the bottom of the navigator and choose Add Exception Breakpoint.